# スタック・オーバーフローは回答者を指定して質問する機能はありますでしょうか？

Tags: サポート, 質問の仕方

追加で訊きたいことがあるのですが、コメントではなく、新規で回答者を指定した追加質問をしたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Metaで扱われるべき話題だと思いますが、とりあず回答者を有償で雇うべきではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 7):

スタック・オーバーフローではそのようなことはできません。たとえば [Quora](https://jp.quora.com/) という Q&A サイトには特定のユーザーに回答リクエストを送る機能がありますが、スタック・オーバーフローにこのような機能はありません。代わりに、単に新しく質問するようにしてみてください。

スタック・オーバーフローは、その場限りの Q&A で終わらせるような投稿を意図していません。プログラミングにおいては、ある質問への最良の回答が年を経て変わったり、場合によって複数の回答がありえたりすることがよくあります。そのような場合でも Q&A としての質がなるべく落ちないように、質問者が回答を解決済みとした後も回答を投稿できるようにしていたり、他人が投稿を編集できるようにしていたりといった仕組みを用意しています。

個人的な考えとしては、ご提案の「＠佐藤さん　回答お願いしたいです」のような質問のやり方は、このようなスタック・オーバーフローの文化にあまり沿っていないかなと考えています。

このため、もしある質問の回答やコメントから新しく疑問が浮かんだ場合は、それを新しく別の質問として投稿することをお勧めしています。その際、疑問のもととなった投稿へのリンクを質問文の中に貼っておくと文脈が分かりやすいでしょう。

もし文脈に関わっていたユーザーさんが新しい投稿を見れば回答くださるかもしれませんし、その投稿を見た別のユーザーがもっと別の回答をくださるかもしれません。このようにより多くのユーザーが回答できるようにすることで、より良い回答を集めるというのがスタック・オーバーフローのやり方だと理解しています。

Comment: 蛇足ですが、プログラミング系の Q&A サイトでは、 teratail が回答者へ回答リクエストを送る機能を備えています（回答者側でオプトアウト出来るようになっていますが）。

Answer (score 4):

質問者さんが行われている質問を見ると、「EmEditor」というソフトウェア製品について、質問したことがサポート担当者(この場合は作者)に即座に伝わって(出来れば即座に)対処してもらえるようにしたい、ということだと思われます。

@nekketsuuu さんの回答のように、このサイトではそういう仕組みは無いのですが、即時性・指名制は無くてもサポートとしての使われ方はあります。
[製品サポートとしてこのサイトを使ってもよいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

質問者さんが行いたいであろう「EmEditor」に関しての質問は、最近1年前くらいから作者によるサポートが充実しているので、ご希望のような仕組みが無くても割と素早い対応が期待できるはずです。

英語版サイトだと、様々な企業が製品サポートの一つの手段として活用している例が多々ありますが、日本語版サイトだとEmEditorの他にはソニーのspresenseとaibo関連くらいでしょうか。印象として狭い分野の企業製品的にはijcadの質問が割とありますが、これはユーザー間の互助になっているようです。

英語版サイトでも即時性・指名制は無いと思われます。

紹介したヘルプ記事にあるように、質問内容に応じて直接的な製品サポート窓口/ユーザーコミュニティ/スタック・オーバーフローのどれに相応しいかを判断してから、スタック・オーバーフローへの質問ならば、対応する「タグ」を付けて質問することが、このサイトでの質問の仕方になるでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。